# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Compilation cannot be undefined after updating to Angular 15

Tags: angular

Updated to Angular v15. When running `ng test` I am getting the following error:

```
⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Compilation cannot be undefined.
    at webpackOptions.entry (D:\wqems\WqEMS-portal\wqems-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\plugins\styles-webpack-plugin.js:58:46)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: undefined,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

Any help on what is going wrong would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

The error comes from the fact that a style file cannot be found during testing. In the angular.json file under "test.styles" the path to the *.(s)css must be adjusted so that they are valid.

e.g.:

"styles": ["src/styles/global.css"]

to

"styles": ["src/styles/global.scss"]

Comment: Serendipitous that you answered this YESTERDAY. I am in the process of porting an Angular project to mobile using Ionic/Capacitor. One of the steps was merging the angular.json files from a new mobile project and the existing Angular project. Sure enough, the test section of the new angular.json was looking for a global.scss instead of styles.scss. Had no idea where to look given the error message. Cheers!

Comment: thank you man, I was scratching my head on this one for far too long.

Answer (score 5):

I had this error, too, after upgrading Angular 14 -> 15, but only in one of my four subprojects.
It turned out this single subproject did not have any karma tests (anymore), so the `findTests()` method of `@angular-devkit` did not find any matches to `**/*.spec.ts` and threw this misleading error.

In my case, I fixed it by simply adding a dummy test case, as I wanted to keep the working test chain for later.

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered this during an update from Angular 14 to 16. I fixed it by also updating ngx-build-plus from 14 to 16.

Comment: This was my problem when migrating from Angular 14 to 15.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in multi-project structure when I did not specify the project, so instead of:

> ng test

it had to be:

> ng test myprojectname

Answer (score 0):

If you only have javascript tests but have no file that ends with spec.ts, then you can create **app.component.spec.ts** next to your **app.component.ts**

```js
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the terminal output, I looked into the library's `project.json` and reviewed the configuration of the broken target. In my case, in `options.styles`, one of the values ​​pointed to a non-existent style file(highlighted on screenshot). I created a file along this path and the script worked

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario the problem was in that I deleted the only .spec file in my app src folder (app.component.spec). So because of 0 tests found it was failing.

Answer (score 0):

My paths for stylesheet are correct still I am facing this error after migration to angular 15, but if I remove styles array I am getting no specs found

Comment: It would be better to write it in the comments, not in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem (ionic-angular) project by running this "npm install --save-dev @types/jasmine"

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the missing `include` parameter in the test spec of angular.json:

```
"test": {
  "builder": "ngx-build-plus:karma",
  "options": {
    "main": "src/test.ts",
    "include": ["**/*.spec.ts"], <<<< that one
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    ...
  }
}
```